# Issue with building aspnet core app as Docker image in Release mode

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, nuget

im building app ins aspnet core using docker, everithing forks fine for iis and docker in debug mode, but when i wanted to build docker image in release mode build fail after trying to download nugets from wrong source.

```
1>/src/datacenter/datacenter.csproj : error NU1101: Unable to find package XXXX. No packages exist with this id in source(s): nuget.org
1>/src/datacenter/datacenter.csproj : error NU1101: Unable to find package XXXX. No packages exist with this id in source(s): nuget.org
1>/src/datacenter/datacenter.csproj : error NU1101: Unable to find package XXXX. No packages exist with this id in source(s): nuget.org
1>/src/datacenter/datacenter.csproj : error NU1101: Unable to find package XXXX. No packages exist with this id in source(s): nuget.org
1>  Generating MSBuild file /src/datacenter/obj/datacenter.csproj.nuget.g.props.
1>  Generating MSBuild file /src/datacenter/obj/datacenter.csproj.nuget.g.targets.
1>  Restore failed in 15.91 sec for /src/datacenter/datacenter.csproj.
1>The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet restore "datacenter/datacenter.csproj"' returned a non-zero code: 1
1>C:\Users\.nuget\packages\microsoft.visualstudio.azure.containers.tools.targets\1.0.1916590\build\Container.targets(222,5): error : An error occurred while attempting to build Docker image.
1>Done building project "datacenter.csproj" -- FAILED.
```

Nugets that are not found should be loaded from local package server.
I also found that when i change container development mode in Container.targets to by always Fast it works properly.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(ContainerDevelopmentMode)' == ''">
  <ContainerDevelopmentMode Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">Fast</ContainerDevelopmentMode>
  <ContainerDevelopmentMode Condition="'$(ContainerDevelopmentMode)' == ''">Regular</ContainerDevelopmentMode>
</PropertyGroup>
```

So my question is should i use "Regular" development mode or does anybody have more correct solution for this issue? Thx